# Reference document for Azure ARM templates outputs

Tags: azure, output, azure-rm-template

I just found it challenging working with the ARM templates outputs since I couldn't find proper documentation for that so every time I want to create an output, the question will be how to name it and address it in the output. I am wondering if there is a document that helps to know about all Azure resources?

Answer (score 0):

By referring to this [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/outputs?tabs=azure-powershell) about outputs in ARM templates, We have created a variable & tried calling that variable in the output block of a ARM template  . we have tested this arm template in our local environment & it is working fine.

```
{
   "$schema":"https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
   "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
   "parameters":{
      
   },
   "functions":[
      
   ],
   "variables":{
      "test":{
         "name":"testing"
      }
   },
   "resources":[
      
   ],
   "outputs":{
      "testResult":{
         "type":"string",
         "value":"[variables('test').name]"
      }
   }
}
```

Power Shell Cmdlet used for deploying the above arm template:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroupName> -TemplateFile C:\Users\Downloads\trigger.json
```

Here is the sample output for reference post the deployment:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what I am looking. My problem is when I want to get a resource property value. I am not sure how to address that properly because sometimes these properties have parent. I hope you get what I mean.